# Split and append paths

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

I have a scenario where i have a variable (`$patharray`) containing an array of paths. eg:

```
/Partners/ftpuser1/Reports/ 
/Partners/ftpuser2/Jan2016/29.01.2016/    
/Partners/ftpuser2/Jan2016/30.01.2016/ 
/Partners/Ftpuser3/January 2016/29.1.16/ 
/Partners/ftpuser4/January 16/ 
/Partners/ftpuser5/TS 2016/January/2901/ 
/Partners/ftpuser5/TS 2016/January/3001/
```

from this I need to create a new array by splitting each path down to first folder, then firstfolder/second folder and so on.  so for above it would need to be:

```
/Partners
/Partners/ftpuser1
/Partners/ftpuser1/Reports
/Partners
/Partners/ftpuser2
/Partners/ftpuser2/Jan2016
/Partners/ftpuser2/Jan2016/30.01.2016
/Partners
/Partners/ftpuser3
/Partners/ftpuser3/January 2016
...
```

Although I can happily split the array by something like:

```
$newpatharray = $patharray -split "/"
```

I'm not sure how I can iterate in such a way to combine the various strings for each object in `$patharray` to get the output format I need.  It would need to account for any path depth as well.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: What do you mean by _It would need to account for any path depth as well._

Comment: There is a VTC as too broad. Unclear maybe because of a minor point but the OP shows what he has / needs and his attempt at a solution. I don't think this should be closed.

Comment: By path depth i mean just that.  each entry may have only 2 subfolders or as many as 10.  whatever i implement will need to take this into consideration and iterate to completion.

Comment: What are you doing with ones that don't match that criteria?

Comment: not sure i understand. this variable will only ever contain paths in a certain format. they then simply need to be split out in the format required. they would never not match this criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split each path, then recombine its elements. Try something like this:

```
$patharray | ForEach-Object {
  $a = $_.TrimEnd('/') -split '/'
  for ($i=1; $i -lt $a.Count; $i++) {
    $a[0..$i] -join '/'
  }
}
```

Comment: in my scenario i had to alter this slightly as it was duplicating the last path and adding a "/".  corrected this by amending for to:
for ($i=1; $i -lt $a.Count-1; $i++)

Comment: You can eliminate duplicates from the output by piping the result into `Select-Object -Unique`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method that works on one string would be something like this:

```
$path = "/Partners/ftpuser1/Reports/" 

# The where-object will drop the leading and trailing entries from the splits. 
$split = $path -split "/" | Where-Object{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}
for($splitIndex = 0; $splitIndex -lt $split.Count; $splitIndex++){
    # Need to add back leading slash

    "/" + ($split[0..$splitIndex] -join "/")
}
```

Could easily wrap that up in a `ForEach-Object` to process many paths.

A loop involving `Split-Path` might be more reliable for this (I got my hand slapped for string manipulation on paths once). You would have to changes the slashes of the output though as `Split-Path` would reverse them.

```cs
function Split-PathRecursive($path){
    # Split the path to get the parent
    $parent = Split-Path $path -Parent

    if($parent -ne "\"){
        # The parent is not the root path. Continue to process.
        $parent
        Split-PathRecursive $parent
    }
}

$pathArray = .....

$pathArray | ForEach-Object{
    # Get all the parent paths. Also need to change the slashes and how it is sorted.
    (Split-PathRecursive $_) -replace "\\","/" | Sort-Object
    # Display the full path as well
    $_
}
```